# Construct $2$-paradoxical tournaments of order $n$ for $n\geq 21$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Recall that a 2-paradoxical tournament is a directed graph $(V,E)$
with the property that for any pair $v_1 \neq v_2 \in V$, there is
a $v_3\in V$ such that $(v_1,v_3)\in E$ and $(v_2,v_3)\in E$.

A well-known probabilistic argument shows that when 
$n\Bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^{n-2}\Bigg)<1$ (which holds for $n\geq 21$), there is a $2$-paradoxical tournament on $n$ vertices.

The only explicit construction I know is the Paley graph, which works only when
$n$ is a prime with $n\equiv 3 ({\sf mod} \ 4)$. Can the construction be somewhat extended to any arbitrary $n\geq 21$ ?

Comment: Do you mean instead that $(v_3, v_1)$ and $(v_3, v_2)$ are arcs?  i.e. every pair of vertices is dominated by some other vertex?

Comment: @ManuelLafond  That's what I mean. Depending on the convention, "$x$ is dominated by $y$" can be expressed by either $(x,y)\in E$ or $(y,x)\in E$.

Comment: OK then.  I think if you take any $2$-paradoxical tournament on $n$ vertices, you can create one on $n + 1$ vertices by just adding a vertex that gets dominated by EVERY vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [Schutte Tournament Problem](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/39-Tournament%20Dice/mathgames_07_11_05.html).

There is actually a way to do it with 19 vertices, such that for any 3 vertices there is a fourth that beats them all.

[image: Schutte tournament]